# Grouping using linq to entity return non correct result

Tags: c#, linq, group-by, linq-to-entities

In my recent application, i have a `Document` entity and this document can refer from a user to another user, also each group of users has a `DocumentStation`; these refers logged in `DocumentStationHistory` table:
[image]

Now, i want list all last document refers that loges in `DocumentStationHistory` table to a `Dictionary` using EF code first(group by `documentId`).
so i wrote these method:

```
public Dictionary<int, DocumentStationHistory> GetLastDocumentStationHistoryListOfDocuments(string criteria)
{
        Dictionary<int, DocumentStationHistory> result = new Dictionary<int, DocumentStationHistory>();
        using (IUnitOfWork uow = new MyContext())
        {
            DocumentStationHistoryRepository repository = new DocumentStationHistoryRepository(uow);
            result = repository.All().
                Include(x => x.DocumentStation).
                Where(criteria,new object[]{}).
                OrderBy(d=>d.DocumentId).
                OrderBy(d=>d.DocumentStationHistoryId).
                GroupBy(g => (int)g.DocumentId).
                ToDictionary(g => (int)g.Key, g => g.LastOrDefault());
            return result;
        }
}
```

it return a dictionary, but the result isn't correct, it doesn't return the **last** refer of each document, also the `DocumentStation` navigation property, in the result is `null`.
where is my mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two problems for the ordering:

- You're using `OrderBy` twice, which almost certainly doesn't do what you think it does. You should usually use `OrderBy` followed by `ThenBy`
- I don't believe `GroupBy` is guaranteed to maintain the ordering of the rest of the sequence. You should order *within* the grouping:

  ```
  result = service.All()
          .Include(x => x.DocumentStation)
          .Where(criteria, new object[]{})
          .GroupBy(g => (int)g.DocumentId)
          .ToDictionary(g => (int)g.Key, 
                        g => g.OrderBy(d => d.DocumentId)
                              .ThenBy(d => d.DocumentStationHistoryId)
                              .Last());
  ```

(There's no need to use `LastOrDefault` - there *has* to be at least one element, otherwise there wouldn't be a group.)

An alternative to using `Last` would be to use `OrderByDescending` and `ThenByDescending`, then `First`, by the way.

I don't know about the `DocumentStation` inclusion part, I'm afraid.

Comment: thanks, the group by problem solved, but the navigation properties are null yet.

Comment: @Masoud: It may be worth separating that into a separate question... ideally having removed the grouping part if you can. (If you *don't* group, does it keep the navigation property?)

Comment: Yes, If i don't group, it keeps the navigation property.